# Filtering out NULL entries in a SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, null

I'm using SQLite to retrieve data inside an iOS app I'm developing.

Of the dataset i've been given by the client there are a lot of entries than contain columns with NULL values.

I want to make sure I filter these out so they aren't shown in the app.

I've tried all sorts of different syntax combinations, with no joy, they still keep appearing.

This is my current SQL

```
select * from bn_main order by RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

I need it to look in the 'meaning' column and perform a WHERE to identify and therefore remove any entries that have a NULL value in that column.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 5):

NULL [is a special case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_logic).
That means you can't do something like `WHERE meaning <> NULL`.
Instead you would use `IS` / `IS NOT`, e.g.:

```
  select meaning 
    from bn_main 
   where meaning IS NOT NULL
order by RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

---

Edit based on comment:
If you've tried this and are still getting results, the values to which you refer are not NULLs.
Instead filter out columns containing whitespace:

```
  select meaning 
    from bn_main 
   where TRIM(meaning) <> ''
order by RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yeah I already tried the IS/IS NOT method and those values were still  returned.